# Using bootstrap popover to show result in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code to get temperature of London from Open weather API. It works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css" />

        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function foo(callback) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: callback
                });
            }

            function myCallback(result) {
                var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
                var Kelvin = 272;
                var Centigrade = Math.round(temp-Kelvin);

                if (Centigrade <= 25) {
                    //alert("Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C");
                    var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
                    temp.style.fontSize = "20px";
                    temp.innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , Cool&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo2.svg\"/>";
                    //document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , Cool&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo2.svg\"/>";
                }
                else if (Centigrade > 25) {
                    var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
                    temp.style.fontSize = "20px";
                    temp.innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , Cool&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo3.svg\"/>";
                    //document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , It's Hot !!! "+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo3.svg\"/>";
                }
            }
        </script>

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 75px;"> 
            <img src="img/temlogo.svg" width="35" height="35" onclick="foo(myCallback);"/>
        </div>

        <p id="temp"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I tried with bootstrap for some nice visualization :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Temperature" data-content="40C">Temperature</a>
</html>
```

It is dissmissable popover.
Now what I am trying is I want get temperature as popover element. ie. if I click on image button, it should trigger temperature acquiring function and then show the temperature and the image related to that in popover box. So here is two challenge I am facing.

- Setting a image instead of the red button and then temperature data
- List item and the image ie. Tlogo2.svg to be appeared in that pop
  over box.

So can anyone suggest how to set that?

For  more clarification I am adding another code. Here in data content shows function name. But I want the result of the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//Function

function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: callback
    });
}

function myCallback(result) {
var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
var Kelvin = 272;
var Centigrade = temp-Kelvin;
alert("Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C");
//document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C";
}


$(function() {
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(myCallback);
            });
    </script>
</body>
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Temperature" data-content= "myCallback(result);" >Temperature</a>

</html>
```

Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Popover's Options to beautify your popover. Using these options you can have complete control over the functionality and appearance of your popover.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc1xj3sn/1/) only demonstrates a few of these options...

**Js Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".popover-examples a").popover({
            title : 'Weather App',
            trigger: 'hover',
            template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /><span>Just an example of inserting image in a Popover...</span></div>'
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <p class="popover-examples">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" >Popover Example</a>
    </p>    
</div>
```

Comment: how to get the function content?I am trying but not getting how exac tly I should do. Probably I am not understanding exactly how it works. can you please show in my code where I have mistaken?

Comment: Hi, can you please explain where my mistake is?

Comment: I can not include function data. can you please tell how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4hza61L/1/).

```
function foo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(result) {
            var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
            var Kelvin = 272;
            var Centigrade = temp-Kelvin;
            var temperature = "Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C";
            $('span.temp-val').text(temperature);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popover-examples a").popover({
        title : 'Weather App',
        trigger: 'hover',
        template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /><span class="temp-val">Just an example of inserting image in a Popover...</span></div>'
    });

    $(".popover-examples a").hover(function() { foo(); })
});
```

You need to call the ajax function at hovering the trigger element. Also, set an identifier for the temperature in your template - this way you can set it to the obtained value using the ajax call.

Comment: Your fiddle works. But the thing is that what I wanted is abstraction. Hence I used ajax call in different function and result show in different function so that I can call query function from different function and then parse and do whatever I want. I am adding one piece of code from mine and from your code but not happening. See edit part