# Javascript function content in bootstrap popover area

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have function content into bootstrap popover area. How to do that?
I am adding one jsfiddle :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/zc1xj3sn/2/
```

Inserting image is done. But I want a function to be inserted.

ANother code I tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//Function

function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: callback
    });
}

function myCallback(result) {
var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
var Kelvin = 272;
var Centigrade = temp-Kelvin;
//alert("Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C");
document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C";
}


$(function() {
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(myCallback);
            });
    </script>
</body>
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Temperature" data-content= "myCallback(result);" >Temperature</a>

</html>
```

Here I want to have populated data from myCallback(result) function

But I am not able to do that, Can anyone please tell me exactly what I have to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using bootstrap popover to show result in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902332/using-bootstrap-popover-to-show-result-in-it)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AKS I was waiting but no one answered, hence what ashould I do, tell me ? if you have solution, please explain

Comment: @NitsanBaleli the function gives weather data . I want that data in bootstrap popever , whnever i click on that button, it should popover with data in it.

Comment: @anupam_on: I replied on your earlier post. Please check there.

Comment: @AKS check in that question or here I am adding one pastebin : http://pastebin.com/FSDzfFxZ
Check this